GitLab Mail Configuration
I would like to use the mailbox (i.e., /var/spool/mail/$USER) available on the local machine where the GitLab instance is installed for receiving e-mail notifications.
How can I configure the GitLab instance if this is supported?
Version we use is GitLab Community Edition v16.3.5.
